# Hallel on a non rosh chodesh day

Tags: talmud-gemara, hallel, story-identification

I'm looking for the source in the Gemorah which says there was once a community that said Hallel on a day that wasn't Rosh Chodesh, and that even though it wasn't the correct minhag it was seen as something to keep. I think it might be in Maseches Taanis, or the Yerushalmi, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably thinking of the story of Rav's visit to Bavel, recorded on Taanit 28b, but you got the Rosh Chodesh part of it confused.

While most people nowadays are used to thinking of Rosh Chodesh as the best example of a Hallel day, really Rosh Chodesh is not a Hallel day at all. Hallel is recited on the entire holidays of Sukkot and Chanukkah as well as the first day[s] of Pesach and Shavuot [and the Seder night[s]]. That's it.

Rav visited Bavel and was upset to find them reciting Hallel on Rosh Chodesh which is not a traditional Hallel day. He soon calmed down when he noticed they were skipping parts to indicate it was just a fake-Hallel: some nice Psalms to help enliven a minor holiday. That's the custom you see nowadays to recite a fake-Hallel (generally known as "Half Hallel") on Rosh Chodesh [and the latter 6 days of Pesach].

> רב איקלע לבבל חזינהו דקא קרו הלילא בריש ירחא סבר לאפסוקינהו כיון דחזא דקא מדלגי דלוגי אמר שמע מינה מנהג אבותיהם בידיהם
>   Rav came to Bavel. He saw that they read Hallel on Rosh Chodesh. He thought to stop them. Once he say that they were skipping around, he deduced that it was just a custom of their fathers.

Comment: Latter 6 days of Pesach is an actual Chiyuv, though (Erchin 10b explains why it’s just half). Your wording implies it’s just minhag, same as Rosh Chodesh.

Comment: @DonielF Huh???

Comment: “Why on Sukkos do we say full Hallel every day, but on Pesach we don’t say full Hallel every day? Sukkos has different Karbanos each day, but Pesach doesn’t have different Karbanos each day.” The Gemara takes it as a given that we should say Hallel on Pesach every day and only questions why we don’t say full Hallel. Rosh Chodesh doesn’t even show up in that Gemara.

Comment: I know the Gemara. That's a mistaken translation. Where is it from?

Comment: My own. How do you understand it?

Comment: The Gemara means to ask why we say Hallel each day of sukkot but only once on pesach. The implication is indeed that any day of pesach is acceptable for the one hallel. The custom is to do it the first day but if you miss that some say to say a Hallel on a different day. But that seemed like too much detail for this question

Comment: Gomrim Et HaHallel just means saying Hallel, like how the word Gemara means teaching not finishing. The Gemara doesn't used gomrim as opposed to saying some but not gomrim. It never ever refers to a half Hallel or a not gomrim halllel or ימים שאין גומרים בהם את ההלל except sort of in the Gemara in my answer here. If people nowadays stuck to "Hallel" and "fake-hallel" as names then there wouldn't be as much confusion here.

Comment: @donielf do you agree with my explanation or do you maintain that the latter days of pesach are obligatory

Comment: I would say it’s a *valid* reading, but I’m not seeing any evidence that you *have* to read it that way.

Comment: @DonielF Rambam [Megillah veChanukkah 3:5-7](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/952008/jewish/Megillah-vChanukah-Chapter-Three.htm) supports the answer, but his word usage seems to rather conform your understanding of גומרין את ההלל.