Half Hallel without a bracha on Yom Ha'atzma'ut and/or Yom Yerushalayim
There are a number of posts here on Mi Yodeya discussing whether to say Hallel (or Half Hallel) on Yom Ha'atzma'ut and/or Yom Yerushalayim and whether or not to include the brachot at the start and end of Hallel. For example:
Reciting Hallel on Yom Yerushalayim and Answering amen to Hallel on Yom Haatzma'ut among several others.
A further question which intrigues me and to which I have not been able to find an answer or explanation is:
if one is not saying the brachot, why say "half Hallel without including the brachot" rather than "full Hallel without including the brachot"?
Can anyone suggest an answer or explanation? The custom of saying half Hallel without including the brachot on Yom Ha'atzma'ut and/or Yom Yerushalayim appears to be quite common.

https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shabbat.118b.5?lang=bi

Thank you for the link which is certainly interesting. However, I don’t see it as pointing towards an answer.

Why say full hallel?

Thank you @shmosel. My starting point is that reasons are given for saying half Hallel on the last 6 days of Pesach and Rosh Chodesh. My question is in essence why not say full Hallel. Especially if one is not saying the brachot

https://torahmitzion.org/learn/hallel-bracha-not/

@EdwardB there is a reticence to say full hallel on a day when one is perhaps not obligated to do so, out of concern for what is written in Shabbat 118. Reciting half hallel obviates that concern.

@Dov thank you for the link to Rabbi Plaskow's shiur "Hallel With A Bracha – To Be Or Not To Be"  He concludes:
It is clear that Hallel needs to be said on these special days: Yom Ha’atzma’ut and Yom Yerushalayim. There are serious halachic reservations though as to whether a Bracha should be said or not. The Chief Rabbinate of Israel has changed its position on this issue a number of times. Most communities recite Hallel without a Bracha but one should consult his/her local Rabbi for a definite Psak.
I don't think he addresses half Hallel without bracha against full Hallel without a bracha

See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/92811/759 The premise that we need "reasons" to downgrade Hallel is backwards. It's either real Hallel or fake Hallel. If you think YY needs (or may need) "real" Hallel, say full hallel. If you think it doesn't but want to sing some nice songs, say half hallel

@JoelK I think that the key passage in Shabbat 118b is
“One who reads Hallel every day is tantamount to one who curses and blasphemes G-d”
Here we are talking about reading Hallel on one particular day, so I am not certain that concern for what is written there applies. However, perhaps that is the view only of those who do say full Hallel without a bracha.

https://www.koltorah.org/halachah/hallel-on-yom-haatzmaut-by-rabbi-chaim-jachter "The Gemara (Shabbat 118b) condemns those who recite Hallel every day.  Hallel is reserved for special occasions.  The Gemara describes one who does not reserve Hallel for such occasions as a blasphemer. "

It occurs to me that many have the custom of saying Tehillim daily, dividing Sefer Tehillim into 30 parts - see for example https://tehillim-online.com For those who follow that custom and who say the Tehillim of day 24  (Tehillim 113-118) https://tehillim-online.com/daily-tehillim/day-24 are essentially saying full Hallel.
That is of course on one day a month and not every day but some may consider that to fall foul of the strictures of the passages in Shabbat 118b highlighted by @JoelK

Learning Psalms 113-118 as Torah study shouldn't be a problem. Reciting Hallel as a unit of praise to G-d could be.

@EdwardB see אין אומרים הלל. צריך עיון קצת האומרי' תילים בכל יום ומתרמי להם הלל ביום ראש השנה היאך אומרים אותו ונ"ל כיון שא"א אותו דרך שירה רק דרך תחנה ובקש' שרי דהא מנהג פשוט לגמור בליל יה"כ כל תהלים ואומרי' ג"כ הלל וגם י"א תהילי' כל יום ויום והלל בכלל ואמרי' הקורא הלל בכל יום ה"ז מחרף ומגדף אלא ע"כ כדפרישית:
https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.584.1

Rabbi Chaim Jachter the author of the koltorah.org article cited above by @JoelK concludes the article with the following
"It is difficult to arrive at a definitive conclusion whether one should recite Hallel with a Beracha on Yom Haatzmaut.  Hence, most of those who recite Hallel on Yom Haatzmaut omit the Beracha. "
R. Jachter does not appear to be at all troubled by the possibility that saying Hallel on YH may fall within the strictures of Shabbat 118a cited by JoelK above. Nor does R. Jachter appear (to me at least) to advocate saying half Hallel on YH.

I would encourage those posting learned comments here to consider posting an answer.

@אילפא if I understand the Magen Avraham that you have cited correctly, it also addresses concerns about a person who wishes to recite Hallel every day.

Taking into account the learned comments received, I consider that the best answer/explanation that I have been able to find is contained in the passage below from Celebrating Yom Ha’atzma’ut and Yom Yerushalayim by Rav David Brodsky which can be found here:
https://etzion.org.il/en/holidays/yom-yerushalayim/celebrating-yom-ha-atzmaut-and-yom-yerushalayim
“Interestingly, R. Soloveitchik (Nefesh Ha-Rav, p. 97), whose recognition of the significance of the events of 1948 and 1967 is well-documented (see Kol Dodi Dofek, for example), objected to reciting Hallel, as he objected to any other change of the liturgy.  He sanctioned, however, reciting half-Hallel, without a blessing, at the end of Shacharit, as this does not constitute a major change in the liturgy.”

The category "major change" here seems pretty arbitrary/ill-defined.
